# Ошибка при открытие проекта на React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Делаю сайт на React.js при помощи webpack dev server, тут все работает корректно. Сейчас решил попробовать запустить просто index.html файл со слинкованным bundle.js и в результате в консоле получаю ошибку:
Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Структура html:

```
   <body> 
     <div id="container-app"></div>

     <script src="./build/bundle.js"></script>
     <script>
     console.log(document.getElementById('container-app'));
    </script>
   </body>
```

рендерится так:

```
   </Router>,
   document.getElementById('container-app')
```

console.log(document.getElementById('container-app')); - выдает нужный мне контейнер.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а второй блок кода у Вас прям так в рендере? Смущает слэш в начале, который должен быть в конце  </Router>

Comment: Это концовка ReactDOM.render(). Я просто привел только его, чтобы простыню всю не выкладывать, так как сам конейнер берется только тут. сверху конечно есть <Router>

Comment: "рендерится так" - это кусок вашего кода или кусок бандла? А то мало ли во что оно там сбандлилось. Вообще без минимального рабочего примера поможет только старый добрый пошаговый дебаг.

Comment: Ну и плюс Вы уверены что проблема проявляется именно в результате рендера главного роута а не в результате рендера саброутов или там компонента какого-нибудь?

Comment: Это кусок моего кода. Не уверен, просто предположил, что этот контейнер является единственным местом, которое является внешним для всей начинки и именно туда он не может примаунтиться.  Каким образом можно пробовать отследить ошибку? вставка дебагера или консоль лога в каждый компонент?

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky ну если бы я думал что проблема в компоненте, то последовательно позакомменчивал-раскомменчивал все внутренние роуты, пока проблема не исчезнет. Но у вас вероятнее всего проблема на этапе сборки, раз через dev-server работает нормально. Стоит поиграться с вебпак конфигом, может плагин какой шалит, или настройки специфические для дев-сервера

Comment: Я просто закомментил вообще все роуты, оставил только пустой Router и ничего не изменилось)) Что то я делаю совсем не так))

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я пытался импортировать переменные из своего главного js файла, который являся точкой входа для webpack
После перемещения данных в другой файл и импорт уже оттуда, сборка и запуск проекта прошли успешно.